# Can't connect to network using GSM SIM900A

Tags: arduino

I'm new in the arduino community, I spent a lot of days to get up with my gsm sim900A module, but it seems not working it keeps blinking 1 sec, so the sim not registered to the network or something like that, I wonder if anybody has the same problem of me, but I really need help with that.

Thank you

Comment: any help please??

Comment: Have you tested it connecting to arduino? Have you tried to make a call or have you tried to connect to web from arduino ?

Comment: This is a coding Q&A site. For Arduino-related hardware questions go to https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If the problem may be code-related, please add your code to your post. Otherwise, use the suggestion by dda

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, it might fit for  arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: @bummi off-topic ??, i was googling for a weeks and reading documentation about this module, if there is a help to give it will be greatfull, i actually giving up i don't have any answer about this issue for a mounth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [blog](http://www.instructables.com/id/Interfacing-SIM900A-GSM-Modem-with-Arduino/) by [Erfinden](http://www.instructables.com/member/Erfinden/)

Steps :

1. Insert sim and lock it.
2. Connect the adapter and power it
3. Now wait for some time (say 1 minute) and see the blinking rate of ‘status LED’ (GSM module will take some time to establish connection with mobile network)
4. Once the connection is established successfully, the status LED will blink continuously every 3 seconds.

So just blinking an LED doesn't meant that your GSM is not working, it is how it works.

Comment: If this wasn't your problem ( this was what i could understand from your question), comment and add a picture of your connections.

Comment: the status of the LED blink every second, and the connection wasn't established with mobile network.

Comment: it might be because you havn't got a network. Insert it on a mobile and check it.

Comment: i tested the sim Card on a mobile and it seems working, i also disabled the PIN code and i make some calls, messages, but the probleme still persist, it might be a problem with the module.

Comment: So if it still not working means i m sure you are out of options. You need to return the item to buyer and ask for replacement or money back. Ik its bit costly.

Comment: Yes the problem coming from the module, i did everything to fix it but it seems that he cannot register to the network so after all the AT commands and waiting i will return the item. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

GSM Module sim900a is working over 5v. try to power it up from an external source don't use arduino for voltage supply

Comment: Can you elaborate what you meant?

Comment: GSM Module is best over continuous voltage when you are supplying voltage from arduino it is not continuous i mean sometime it drops to 3v which make the GSM module unstable . the best way to work with GSM module to provide it continuous 5v from an external source

Comment: Add it in the answer not as a comment.